# DataSource in an OSGI container

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, osgi

I have a simple Spring App that connects to a DB via an `EntityManager`

So I have to following configuration:

```
<bean id="domainEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="TheManager" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="domainDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.conztanz.persistence.stock.model" />

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="domainDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/dbName" />
    <property name="username" value="xxxx" />
    <property name="password" value="xxxx" />
</bean>
```

This works fine when lunched via a `main` class (loading the AppContext manually)

But, once deployed into `ServiceMix` I get the following error :

```
Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [org.postgresql.Driver]
```

- I've read somewhere that `OSGI` and `DriverManager` don't mix well but I fail to understand why.
- The solution that seems to be a good practice is to expose the `dataSource` as an `OSGI` bundle, do you agree ? and in that case how would you have access to it from a `spring context` to be able to have an `EntityManager` for example ?

Comment: Ugh... Spring??

Comment: yes what about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DriverManager does not work well in OSGi. The easiest way is to use a DataSource directly. Most DB drivers have such a class. If you instantiate it in your app context then it will work. The downside is though that it binds your application to the DB driver as it then will import the packages for the DataSource impl.

A more loosely coupled way is to use [ops4j pax jdbc](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/Create+DataSource+from+config). It allows to create a DataSource as an OSGi service from a config in config admin. So in your app context you just have to add a dependency to a DataSource service. So your application is not bound to the specific DB driver. One typical use case is to use H2 in tests and oracle in production.

Comment: thank you for the reply,I'm trying to use the second solution, I successfully created the DataSource (service:list javax.sql.DataSource shows it), what I  don't quit get is how to access it from the app context ?

Comment: You need to refer to the OSGi service. You can either do that with spring-dm (unfortunately unmaintained) or switch completely to blueprint.

Comment: oh Yeah ? that's weird because I just used   <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="NameUsedInkarafConfigFile" />  in spring config files and it seems to work, ie the entitymanager is not null, Am I missing something ?

Comment: Not sure ... can you paste your spring config somewhere? How do you load the spring config btw?

Comment: spring config : http://pastebin.com/4vDS9MsQ
persistence.xml : http://pastebin.com/4AC60E70

and then i deploy a config file in karaf containing url, password ...

Comment: as for spring config, not sure if I understand your question, but it is loaded automatically when deployed into karaf

Comment: If you are not loading the context by "hand" then you probably already use spring-dm. So you can add a service reference to the DataSource using <osgi:reference id="dataSource" interface="java.sql.DataSource"/>

Comment: How can I verify that I'm using spring-dm ?

Comment: Do not deploy the spring dm bundle and verify that you context is not loaded.